# Differential Equations on Population

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I've been beginning to try to solve some simple differential equations. I reached a problem where there is a polar bear population $p(t)$ and a seal population $s(t)$ that are governed by 
$$\frac{dp}{dt} = p(t) - 3s(t)$$
$$\frac{ds}{dt} = 2p(t) + 4s(t)$$
Assuming a continuous approximation of population. I'm interested in solving for the asymptotic behavior of the populations of polar bears and seals. I was wondering, what would the asymptotic behavior of this function be like if $p(0) = 3000$ and $s(0) = 5000$? If so, is there a good way to solve this using some linear system of equations?

Comment: Do you realise that this system has a simple closed form solution?

Comment: Not only, there is a simple closed form solution as  okrzysik commented, but I suspect that the bears will disappear quite quickly.

Comment: ...And their population will even become negative. What is minus one bear?

Comment: What is 'this' function?